# 3-D Quiver Plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to make a 3-D quiver plot in python 2.7. When I run the quiver3d_demo.py from the matplotlib site, I get a value error that looks like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in        execfile(fname, *where)
202             else:
203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/loisks/Desktop/quiver3d_demo.py in <module>()
 15      np.sin(np.pi * z))
 16 
---> 17 ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1)
 18 
 19 plt.show()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in quiver(self, *args, **kw)
 3802         if not self._hold:
 3803             self.cla()
-> 3804         q = mquiver.Quiver(self, *args, **kw)
 3805         self.add_collection(q, False)
 3806         self.update_datalim(q.XY)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/quiver.pyc in __init__(self, ax, *args, **kw)
395         """
396         self.ax = ax
--> 397         X, Y, U, V, C = _parse_args(*args)
398         self.X = X
399         self.Y = Y

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/quiver.pyc in _parse_args(*args)
357         nr, nc = 1, U.shape[0]
358     else:
--> 359         nr, nc = U.shape
360     if len(args) == 2:  # remaining after removing U,V,C
361         X, Y = [np.array(a).ravel() for a in args]
```

### ValueError: too many values to unpack

Any suggestions? It's not the quiver3d_demo.py either - I have trouble independently making a 3d quiver plot.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an old version of matplotlib.  The [The matplotlib website](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#new-plotting-features) says version 1.4.0 or later is required.